# how to show modal popup window in opera using javascript

Tags: javascript, opera

i am able to show the madal popup window using javascript in IE using the following code:

```
var retVal = window.showModalDialog(PagePath, null, 'dialogWidth:850px;dialogHeight:870px;resizable:no;status:no;help:no;scroll=yes');
```

but its not working in Opera. Though I am able to open a window in Opera using `window.open` but i am not able to get the return value.

I am putting the return value in a hidden field and from code behind I am rediecting to the specified page based on the retun value (value in the hidden field).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `showModalDialog` is an IE specific method. If you want a modal box in other browsers, you'll have to program one yourself. Maybe [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X5DuY/) can get you started.